# Where do you find memo id when sending from coin base to Trezor T stellar

Tags: transactions, lumens, token-wallet

I plugged in Trezor T device and selected stellar currency. It took me to an external wallet in Stellar. I then transferred 1.00 from Coinbase to Stellar wallet and it wanted a memo id which I could not find anywhere so I entered A1 . This worked but then I transferred more it has been delayed by coinbase. My question is where do I find the memo id and as I have connected by Trezor T does this mean that it is a private address as it doesn’t a memo I’d and therefore it is ok to enter A1? I am worried I have lost the transaction now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To find the memo, you'll need to specify it when you conduct the transaction. See Step #5 on this page here: https://wiki.trezor.io/Stellar_(XLM)